# Cómo hacer que este checkbox devuelva 1 y no true

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap, checkbox

Tengo este código de un checkbox:

```
{
    key: 'miClave',
    type: 'checkbox',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'Marca esta opción para que sea 1'
    }
},
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que su respuesta cuando lo marco sea 1 y no true?

Answer (score 1):

Al `input type="checkbox"` puedes añadirle dos propiedades más:

```
ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0"
```

Con las cuales pones qué valor quieres para `true` y `false`.

```js
angular.module('App', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {

  $scope.getNumber = function() {
    return $scope.testc
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="App">
  <form name="myForm" ng-controller="Ctrl">

    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="testc" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" />  <br /> {{getNumber()}}
  </form>
</div>
```